# Hotjar regex for matching prestashop product pages

Tags: regex, prestashop, hotjar

I have installed HotJar script on my Prestashop web site.

I am tracking now main page.

I have activated now Friendly URL and mod_rewrite on site.

I would like to track as well all pages that matches Product page : (without Friendly URLwould be /myprestashop.com/index.php?controller=product&id_product)

I have taken from Presta code following regexp for product pattern pages :

"#^/(([_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*)/)?(?P[0-9]+)-([_a-zA-Z0-9\pL\pS-]*).html$#u"

However if I paste that in hotjar regexp field it says that it's invalid.

Could you please help me to reformulate it so could HotJar accept it ?

Thank you

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I have used https://regex101.com/ validator and that it's really helpfull.

It seems that has to be like a javascript flavor :

/(([_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*)/)?([0-9]+)-([_a-zA-Z0-9\pL\pS-]*).html$

Hotjar site has accepted it.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you managed to solve your issue yourself. Sorry I didn't get here in time to help out :).You're spot on btw! we require a JS flavored regex for our targeting.

It's vaguely mentioned in our [regex docs](https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115012727628-Using-Regular-Expressions-to-Target-Multiple-Pages), but that doesn't really help much when you're in the product.

I'll make sure that we at least insert a link to the docs in the targeting UI. Thanks for finding this UX flaw for us!

Comment: HEllo eKIK ! thank you for answering ! what improvement suggestion I have for Hotjar: to propose automatically for shops those kind of regexp. for example if is default presta to propose a set for product page and listing page. an so on for other ecomm solution.

Comment: That's a really good idea Daniel - some kind of "common regex library", which could also include platform specific ones (like Prestashop etc).